# 2 form at the same page flask

Tags: python, flask

Hello guys hope u doing fine, I got this project and in home page of my website i have two form
1 to login and the other to upload a file however every time i submit with any form the same function keeps getting executed please help.
this is the html code

```
<!--login-->
    <section class="bg-dark text-light p-5 text-center">
        <div class="container"> 
            <h2>First step </h2>
            <form action = "http://localhost:5000" method="post" name="login" >
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="hide-md-lg">
                        <h4>Sign in to your <span class="text-warning">Linkedin account</span>  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <br><br>        
                    <input  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--upload excel--> 
    <section class="bg-dark text-light p-4">
        <div class="container bg-primary rounded border-0 p-5">
            <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="container">
                <h5 class="mt-2">Choose an excel file</h5>
                <h6 class="mb-3"><span class="text-warning">NB: first 2 columns have to be: "Prénom" and "Nom"</span></h6> 
                </div>
                    <form class="input-group" action = "http://localhost:5000" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" name="upload">
                        <input class="form-control size-file" type="file" name="file" id="formFile">
                        <input  class="btn  btn-dark" type = "submit" value="Start scraping" >              
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and this is the backend part

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST' :
       f = request.files['file']
       f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
       df = pd.read_excel(f.filename)...............



@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login_info():
    if request.method == 'POST'  and 'Sign in to your' in request.form['h4']:
        user_info = request.form.get("username")
        pass_info = request.form.get("password")
```

Comment: You can't associate a single route with multiple function. You need to tell each form a different route in the `action=""` parameter. One should lead to something like /upload and the other to /login, each associated with the desired function

Comment: so i can't put two forms in the same page ?

Comment: You definitely can, but each form should link to a different route, even if they ultimately return the same template. It will show the same resulting page, but the process of the POST is different

Answer (score 1):

Although unable to try it this way, I updated your code with different `action` parameters.

```
<!--login-->
    <section class="bg-dark text-light p-5 text-center">
        <div class="container"> 
            <h2>First step </h2>
            <form action = "{{url_for('login_info')}}" method="post" name="login" >
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="hide-md-lg">
                        <h4>Sign in to your <span class="text-warning">Linkedin account</span>  </h4>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <br><br>        
                    <input  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--upload excel--> 
    <section class="bg-dark text-light p-4">
        <div class="container bg-primary rounded border-0 p-5">
            <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="container">
                <h5 class="mt-2">Choose an excel file</h5>
                <h6 class="mb-3"><span class="text-warning">NB: first 2 columns have to be: "Prénom" and "Nom"</span></h6> 
                </div>
                    <form class="input-group" action = "{{url_for('upload_file')}}" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" name="upload">
                        <input class="form-control size-file" type="file" name="file" id="formFile">
                        <input  class="btn  btn-dark" type = "submit" value="Start scraping" >              
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the `@app.route` should lead to two function :

```
@app.route('/upload_file', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST' :
       f = request.files['file']
       f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
       df = pd.read_excel(f.filename)...............



@app.route('/login_info', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login_info():
    if request.method == 'POST'  and 'Sign in to your' in request.form['h4']:
        user_info = request.form.get("username")
        pass_info = request.form.get("password")
```

If you want both those page to return to your home screen, you just have to tell them to return to this same template with `render_template()` or `redirect()`